# How to place an Html form over an Image

Tags: html, css, image, forms

I wanted to place a form over a mobile phone image. I tried everything I could think of (I'm new to html and Css).

Here is a link to my work    [PicText](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aZpQQN) `.`

This is the 
[Image](http://i.imgur.com/YUuTWwr.png?1)

By the way, it is on the middle phone(the Iphone) I am trying to place the form on.

Comment: You can put zindex for form

Comment: `background-image`?

Comment: Yeah kinda like a background image @4castle

Comment: Fairly easy to set up a background image on the containing div and then adjust the form CSS to fit the middle. I actually worked it all out... then clicked Save for your code... but I don't want to sign up for SoloLearn... so... it all vanished with that requirement. Too bad the code's not in CodePen or jsFiddle where you aren't *required* to register at their site.

Comment: Thanks @Scott  I'll try to set up the code at CodePen

Comment: Here is the work in CodePen (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aZpQQN) @Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the div around the form, then add a `background-image` to that div.... then adjust the size and position of the form to fit the image:

The only HTML adjustment was the addition of the class to the div below:

```
  <div class="formhold">
    <form method="post" action="action_page.php">
```

Essential CSS

```
.formhold {
  width: 600px; /* width of the image */
  height: 520px; /* height of the image */
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/YUuTWwr.png?1) no-repeat center top;
}

form {
  display: block;
  width: 180px; /* width to use in the middle phone screen */
  margin: 0 auto; /* centers form over image */
  padding-top: 120px; /* moves form down from top of image */
}
```

[image]

## [**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/th4gunc1/)

Note that I **adjusted your the CSS padding and margins on your text and password inputs** as well so the form would fit vertically. More refinement is most likely desired, but this should at least get you started.

<sub>(Personal preference is jsFiddle, the others just require signup. With jsFiddle I can choose to sign in or not.. the code isn't lost.)</sub>

Comment: i also suggest adding `overflow-y: scroll` to `.formhold`.

Comment: good point @WoodrowBarlow ideally the form fields would be in a separate div with overflow properties., leaving the submit button outside the div so it remains in position. I didn't want to get into many refinements of the HTML though.