# Float a form over an image and down to the right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello Stack Overflowians, I'm trying to float a form over a background image and I think I'm not doing it right. This is for our company gateway that I'm having to rebuild after many years in production. Below is what I have so far. The first image is my version of it. See how I got the background image to center? https://postimg.cc/nCmTfxVz Now that parts working good.

Next is the old site and the image is way to the left. https://postimg.cc/jn76T6b9

Not meaning to trick our clients, but they really like our old gateway right now, so I'm trying to style it as close as possible to the original one. As you can see, I've been successful in getting it close. (The rounded corners on the new input boxes are fine.) And the placement of the inputs are good with me too. It's just that, I don't believe I'm doing this right, as you can see in my HTML `<div class="row" style="margin-top: -190px;">` that's what I'm having to do for now to push the whole form down.

I noticed here ([How to place an Html form over an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041253/how-to-place-an-html-form-over-an-image)) about half-way down the page, @Scott added `padding-top: 120px;` to the `form{}` code. I tried adding his CSS but it pushed the form way down off the image.
Note: I still have to place a header up above with the "Registration" and "Forgot Password" links, but I'm not worried about that. I'll work that out myself. If you guys could just steer me in the right direction, or show me a better way to do this, I would be very appreciative. Thanks.

Oh, and here's what it looked like when I would go into responsive mode in Firefox like I was viewing it on a phone. https://postimg.cc/qtq30ccL So I added the media query stuff as you can see in the CSS. And now I have it looking like this. https://postimg.cc/m14q5G7D

Oh, and one more thing. Here's something else to keep in mind. Every now and then, we will be putting a message bar at the top of the page that says something like "Gateway will be down for maintenance over the weekend." or something similar. I will probably just put a Bootstrap banner up there since its so easy and quick to do. So it would be nice to just be able to float everything down while I do that. Just something extra to keep in mind. (-: So below is all of my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <title>Gateway Reboot v.3.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="Contact-Form-Clean.css"/-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    body{
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .coolbox { /* this is a hold-over from the old web application */
      display: block;
      font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;/* was 12.87px */
      line-height: 16px;
      border: 2px #708090 solid;
      height: 22px;
      width: 155px;
      padding-left: 6px;/* because Bootstrap was putting too much padding on the left */
    }
    label{
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    form{
      margin-left: 200px;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      form{
        margin-left: 25%;
      }
      /*img {
        opacity: 0.6;
      }*/
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      form{
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-top: 15%;
      }
      img {
        opacity: 0.1;
      }
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <img src="bigbackKey.png" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" alt="Sample Image" />
                <!--section class="contact-clean"-->
                 <div class="row" style="margin-top: -190px;"><!--Just doing this for now to push the "form" row down. I know it's probably not the right way to do it.--> 
                  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="username">Username</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control coolbox" id="username" name="username" />
                        <!--/div-->
                        <!--By combining these 2 divs, it removed a big gap between the username box/label and password box/label.-->
                        <!--div class="form-group"-->
                          <label for="password">Password</label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control coolbox" id="password" name="password" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"><button class="coolbox" type="submit">Login</button></div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                <!--/section-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form is inside a `div col-md-6`. That column could have a CSS `background` (your image). Then your form will still be inside that column with the background added.

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks Rob. So I took your advice and I decided to just put the `background-image` using CSS to that one `col-md-6` div, but I had some weird results. It was just showing the image in that one div. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: Can you twist my idea around slightly? It doesn't necessarilly have to affect just one Div. It's just a form in a Div and the background of the Div is your image.

Comment: I'm sorry Rob, I'm sort of confused. But I'll keep playing around with things. Thanks man.

Comment: It will all come good in the end. Some time today either you, me or somebody else will be posting the answer here. Keep going :)